# Does the 'Taxonomist' badge include tags created on other people's questions?

Tags: support, badges

The Taxonomist badge is awarded if 50 questions use a tag you've created, according to the [Badges](https://meta.superuser.com/help/badges) page

Does this count for me or for the OP if I create a tag when *editing* a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does count for you since you created the tag. It doesn't matter if you create it when editing others' question or adding your own.

Comment: 'Yes it does' - count for me you mean?

Comment: @Robotnik yeah, you're the one who created it, so it counts for you.